# How do I set the SoapObject value in kSoap2

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I want to place a value in the root SoapObject in the soap body.

```
<envelope>
  <body>
    <request>34</request>
  </body>
</envelope>
```

Is there a way to set the value of the SoapObject I cannot change the server side it has to be in this format.  Or is there away to set the output object as a Property?

I'm lost and about to build it from scratch and send it via http at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to do this is to write a simple class, which extends `SoapPrimitive` and implements `KvmSerializable`. It's look like this:

```
class CustomProperty extends SoapPrimitive implements KvmSerializable
{
    public CustomProperty(String namespace, String name, String value)
    {
        super(namespace, name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int index)
    {
        return this.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info)
    {
        info.setValue(toString());
        info.setName(getName());
        info.setNamespace(getNamespace());
    }
}
```

Using:
`envelope.setOutputSoapObject(new CustomProperty(null, "request", "34"));`